# Why is 'bark someone' improper English?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I read that *bark someone* isn't proper English, but, even if in a phrasal verb construct, it is used in a sentence from "Six Weeks in Saratoga: How Three-Year-Old Filly Rachel Alexandra Beat the Boy and Became Horse of the Year" by Brendan O'Meara.

> With the coils of the bike's suspension barely depressed, the bike's
>   owner bolted toward her and barked her off the bike, inspecting for
>   any damages.

So, I was wondering why one cannot *bark someone* if, according to the above writer, *bark someone off* is grammatical.

Note that dictionaries I have consulted don't have an entry for *bark off* — even if, for example, *bark out* exists —, so I'm not sure what the meaning of "bark off" is in that context.

Comment: Actually, [the dog barked me](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22dog+barked+me%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) occurs several times in Google Books. But regardless of the discussion under @J.R.'s answer, I don't think it's a "proper English" usage. It's just that creative writers aren't really obliged to stick to "the rules" (which we assume they *know*, but choose to ignore in certain contexts). In this case, it's not a good example for a non-native speaker to copy.

Comment: If you can be laughed off the stage, you can be barked off a bike. To say that these authors are being creative and ignoring the "rules" is to misrepresent what is going on. Our audience may be English learners, but they are also adult learners; I'm not going to pretend that English has "rules" that are being broken by established and accomplished writers.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this could be paraphrased as: "...and yelled at her loudly until she got off the bike."

The verb *bark* can be used when describing someone yelling at someone else, especially in an annoying or intimidating manner:

> She barked commands at her employees all day long.

In this case, she barked until someone got off the bike, which can be expressed as was done by the writer:

> She barked her off the bike.

The same might be said if someone was yelling so much in a threatening way, that the other person ran out of the house in fear:

> He barked her out of the house.

It's an unusual construct, but there's nothing ungrammatical about it.

Comment: +1 It's not in itself an established idiom, but it's an idiomatic construction: *VERB Object preposition Location*. An intransitive verb may thus be transitivized. You might "scream him out of the room" or "bluster him into submission" or "swagger them under the rug".

Comment: Adding to the above, you probably read that "bark someone" is not grammatical in a book (or whatever) that was trying to emphasize that the (by far) more usual expression is "bark at someone".

Comment: It's so unusual I think in the context of ELL it might be more appropriate to simply say *to bark somebody [into some changed state]* is not a valid construction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The construction specifically with *bark* is indeed rare; but I think the construction itself is so common that learners would benefit from learning about it: "shouted him off the stage", "laughed her out of court", "spent him into the poorhouse", "sang them to sleep".

Comment: @StoneyB: All sorts of oddball usages *may* be acceptable when they're from the pen of a competent native speaker. But in general, I think if non-native speakers come away with the impression this sort of construction is "normal", they'll end up sounding weird rather than fluent more often than not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers OP's question is about **understanding** the phrase, which is an unusual use of a perfectly "normal" construction. ... So they sound weird - so what? Most native speakers can't utter three consecutive 'correct' sentences! These learners are going to sound weird anyway, and it's better to put tools in their hands that allow them to participate in dialogue than to forbid them participation because they might embarrass themselves.

Comment: @StoneyB: Hmmm. I think it would be more "idiomatic" if the bike's owner had ***tossed her off** the bike*, but if OP tried to understand that one by looking up ["toss off"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/To+toss+off) they probably wouldn't get far. What it amounts to is as a learner you have to look for a credible *semantic* interpretation based on the core meaning of key verbs/nouns, before looking for some strange idiomatic meaning that may be unnecessary.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Exactly. And if you're aware of the **pattern** it's easy to interpret the unusual lexeme. As NSs, we're 'aware' at some level of the pattern in *shout off* and *laugh off* and *jeer off*, so *bark off* makes intuitive sense. The NNS doesn't have that pattern; but even a very rare use like *bark off* provides us an occasion to pass that pattern on. Teach a man to fish ...

Comment: @StoneyB: I'm still not convinced. To *bark off/out [e.g., peremptory orders]* seems like a reasonable figurative usage it does no harm for NNS to be consciously aware of. But to *bark [someone] [unwillingly, into a different state]* just seems to me to be an exercise in juggling the semantics of the primary verb until you arrive at a credible interpretation. I don't really see what's to be gained by pointing out similarities with *boo, jeer, laugh, shout [somebody] [**off** the stage, or whatever]*. That doesn't help much with *the dog barked the squirrel **up** the tree*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not suggesting NNS need to be aware of *bark X off Y*. I can't imagine using it myself, let alone an NSS. I'm suggesting that they'll benefit from being aware of *VERB X off Y* and *VERB X Prp Y*; *bark* is just the occasion OP has handed us for informing them.

Comment: @StoneyB: I think we've finally reached a point of agreement! Yes, *VERB X Prp Y* is indeed a "general-purpose" construction for *force X into state/location Y by VERBing*. Even in ordinary speech, people can get *very* creative about exactly which verb to use if, say, *X = square peg*, and *Y = round hole* (in that type of context, it's not at all uncommon to hear complete nonce-words used for VERB).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: RE: _All sorts of oddball usages may be acceptable .. but if non-native speakers come away with the impression this sort of construction is "normal", they'll end up sounding weird rather than fluent..._ I only explained the construct that was asked about; I don't see any benefit to not explaining it out of fear it'll be misused. To say, "in the context of ELL it might be more appropriate to simply say [it] is not a valid construction" is to bury one's head in the sand. With an odd usage from a book, better to **explain _why_ it's acceptable** than declare it "invalid."

Comment: I (a native English speaker) didn't understand the phrase in the cited context when I read it. That, I think, suggests that it should be used cautiously. Given that "bark" has a transitive meaning that is quite different may also be a problem.